# Adding methods to extensions

Tags: c#, queue, extension-methods

I found some code to make a `Queue` of a fixed size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500711/6329629). Now I'm trying to add an `Average` method to this, but I get the message:

> 'Queue' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Average(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

For a normal `Queue` I can use the `Average` method. Why can't I access it here?

Also first converting  to an array or list and then taking the average does not work: `queue.ToArray().Average()`.

Finally, why is it better to wrap this extension in a new class, instead of inheriting from `Queue` by doing `public class FixedSizeQueue<T> : Queue<T>`?

```
public class FixedSizeQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> queue;

    public FixedSizeQueue(int capacity)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
        queue = new Queue<T>(capacity);
    }

    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    public int Count { get { return queue.Count; } }

    public T Average()
    {
        return queue.Average();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        queue.Clear();
    }

    public T ElementAt(int i)
    {
        return queue.ElementAt(i);
    }

    public T Enqueue(T item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        if (queue.Count > Capacity)
        {
            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            //if you want this to do something else, such as return the `peek` value
            //modify as desired.
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return queue.Peek();
    }

    // Got it from somewhere, don't know where.
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)queue).GetEnumerator();
    }

    //IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    //{
    //    return ((IEnumerable<T>)queue).GetEnumerator();
    //}
}
```

Comment: How do you expect `Average()` to work on your type `T`?

Comment: What do you mean with that @DavidG?

Comment: Let's say it was a `Queue<string>`, what would be the average of the strings `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: It is better to create extension method instead of inherite it because of Composition over inheritance principle [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) As @DavidG mentioned you can't use `Average` with `string` but you can create extension method that will relate only to your type.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I just need it for numbers. So I first need to check if it is a float, double, int etc, before I can average?

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no "numeric" restriction in where condition. So your check might be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this method because it's extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` (`Average` without parameters is a group of extension methods for `IEnumerable<int>`, `IEnumerable<double>` and so on) and your `FixedSizeQueue` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface. If you implement it (and delegate implementation to `_queue`:

```
public class FixedSizeQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    private Queue<T> queue;

    public FixedSizeQueue(int capacity) {
        Capacity = capacity;
        queue = new Queue<T>(capacity);
    }

    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return queue.Count; }
    }

    public void Clear() {
        queue.Clear();
    }

    public T Enqueue(T item) {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        if (queue.Count > Capacity) {
            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
        else {
            //if you want this to do something else, such as return the `peek` value
            //modify as desired.
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public T Peek() {
        return queue.Peek();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>) this.queue).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use `Average` as usual:

```
var queue = new FixedSizeQueue<float>(10);
var result = queue.Average();
```

For queues of non-numeric types you will still be able to use `Average` overload which accepts parameters:

```
var queue = new FixedSizeQueue<string>(10);
var result = queue.Average(x => x.Length);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it says: `'FixedSizeQueue<float>[]' does not contain a definition for 'Average'`. And when I add `public T Average() { return queue.Average(); }` in `FixedSizeQueue` I get the same error as in my question.

Comment: @Roald how did you end up with `FixedSizeQueue<float>[]`? That is array of queues, you need `FixedSizeQueue<float>`?

Comment: @Roald I've updated with full modified implementation of `FixedSizeQueue`. You can copy paste it and compare with what you have to spot a problem.

Comment: Ah yes it is an array. My mistake, sorry. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Average` only works for the following type : `decimal`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`.

Right now your collection is `T` which is not possible to average.
You need to use a selector on your collection and write it down directly.

Example, lets says you have the following class

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Title {get;set;} = "";
    public double Value {get;set;} = 0d;
}
```

and say you have your queue as :

```
FixedSizeQueue<MyData> queue = new FixedSizeQueue<MyData>();
// add some data ...
queue.Enqueue(new MyData());
```

Now to get the average you need to tell what you want to average and here i want the `Value` property then i would do this (very explicit)

```
double averageValue = queue.ToList().Average(data => data.Value);
```